# how do I use swiftui to add green insert row like the previous UITableViewCell .insert editingStyle

Tags: swiftui

how do I use swiftui to add the red delete buttons and green insert row like the previous UITableViewCell .insert editingStyle

similar to the image below. cant seem. to find anything like that in List

[image]

Comment: For others reference: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle.insert: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/editingstyle/insert

Comment: that's for UIKit. I need the equivalent for SwiftUI. ive had to fake it for now.